# toolbar from main activity not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

I have made a toolbar in main activity where i have set the scroll flags to it but the problrm is that in a fragment hide and show is not working except one fragment it is working in all other fragments and moreover my fab is also not visible but the fab is showing in the preview i do not know where i'm going wrong so please if some one can help me out here

MainActivity.java

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

main activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <!-- AppBarLayout is a wrapper for a Toolbar in order to apply scrolling effects. -->
    <!-- Note that AppBarLayout expects to be the first child nested within a CoordinatorLayout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <!-- Toolbar is the actual app bar with text and the action items -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/White"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

</FrameLayout>

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the fragment where it is not working

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/feed_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you share your java code and a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: sure just a moment

Comment: If you want your fab button to show use `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` so that the `RecyclerView` doesn't cover the button.

Comment: @LieForBananas it is not just about fab it is about toolbar

Comment: @Smith I know, I just suggested a solution for one of your problems, that is why I commented and not answered.

Comment: ok @LieForbananas thanks i appreciate that

Comment: What happens when use `FrameLayout`?